# How to aggregate JSONB PostgreSQL 10

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-10

I have table with ids and jsonb colums

```
1, "{"a" : {"per" : 0.45, "number" : 1}}"
1, "{"b" : {"per" : 3.13, "number" : 7}}"
2, "{"a" : {"per" : 14.73, "number" : 33}}"
2, "{"b" : {"per" : 85.27, "number" : 191}}"
3, "{"a" : {"per" : 40.63, "number" : 91}}"
4, "{"a" : {"per" : 1.79, "number" : 4}}"
4, "{"b" : {"per" : 2.68, "number" : 6}}"
```

Need to group values by ids and get this result

```
1, "{"a" : {"per" : 0.45, "number" : 1}, "b" : {"per" : 3.13, "number" : 7}}"
2, "{"a" : {"per" : 14.73, "number" : 33}, "b" : {"per" : 85.27, "number" : 191}}"
3, "{"a" : {"per" : 40.63, "number" : 91}}"
4, "{"a" : {"per" : 1.79, "number" : 4}, "b" : {"per" : 2.68, "number" : 6}}"
```

Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in aggregate for that, but you can easily create your own:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE jsonb_merge(jsonb) 
(
    SFUNC = jsonb_concat(jsonb, jsonb),
    STYPE = jsonb
);
```

Then you can do:

```
select id, jsonb_merge(the_jsonb_column) 
from your_table
group by id
```

Comment: Works pretty well. Thank you.